# Spring binding issues jsp

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am getting 500 always when hit the controller method showed below.

```
@RequestMapping(value ="transferInvoiceHdrForm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
protected ModelAndView showForm(@ModelAttribute("transferInvoice") TransferInvoiceForm trinvoiceform, final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response, Model model)throws Exception {
        TransferInvoiceHdr transferInvoiceHdr = new TransferInvoiceHdr();
        List<TransferInvoice> transferinvoice= transferInvoiceHdrService.getAssetCategoriesandTransfer();
        List<Employees> employees = transferInvoiceHdrService.getAssignEmployee();
        trinvoiceform.setTrinvoiceList(transferinvoice);
        log.info("++++"+trinvoiceform.getTrinvoiceList());
        model.addAttribute("employees", employees.get(0).getFullname());
    //  model.addAttribute("transferinvoice", transferinvoice);
        model.addAttribute("transferInvoiceHdr", transferInvoiceHdr);
        //model.addAttribute("transferInvoice", transferinvoice);

    return new ModelAndView("asset/transferInvoiceHdrForm", model.asMap());
}
```

My Pojo with list of objets looks like

```
public class TransferInvoiceForm {
private List<TransferInvoice> TrinvoiceList;
//getters and setters
```

in my JSP i use path variable as below

```
<form:form method="post" action="/asset/invoice/searchctr" modelAttribute="transferInvoice">
             <fieldset>
              <c:forEach var="transferinvoiceType" items="${transferInvoice.TrinvoiceList}" varStatus="status">
                     <form:select path="TrinvoiceList[${status.index}].assetName" class="col-xs-12 col-lg-5 form-group">
                            <form:option value="0" selected="true">All</form:option>
                            <form:options value="${transferinvoiceType.assetName}"></form:options>
                    </form:select>
                    </c:forEach>
                     <c:forEach var="transferinvoiceType" items="${transferInvoice.TrinvoiceList}" varStatus="status">
                    <form:select path="TrinvoiceList[${status.index}].assettoLocation" class="col-xs-12 col-lg-5 form-group">
                             <form:option value="0" selected="true">All</form:option>
                            <form:options value="${transferinvoiceType.assettoLocation}"></form:options>
                        </form:select>
                     </c:forEach>

                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" class="col-xs-12 col-lg-6 form-group">
                        <fmt:message key="button.search" />
                    </button>
            </fieldset> 
        </form:form>
```

Another useful java bean

```
 public class TransferInvoice {
    private String assetName;
    private String assettoLocation;
    private String actualTransferDate;
    private String scanserialCode;
    private String modelNum;
    private boolean check;
    //getters and setters
```

Any help why i was getting 500. I checked thoroughly and confirmed that problem exits in my jsp binding. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Still i am facing this issue, Can any one have a fresh look?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following process to recover from this situation.
Whenever you are using JSTL form tag so in your jsp page you can use:

```
<form:form commandName="viewModel" method="POST">
```

In controller part you can use your TransferInvoice Model directly to get all the data from your jsp page. And if it is necessary to keep data in TransferInvoiceForm pojo , then you can manage it under the controller.
So you can follow the following code:

```
@RequestMapping(value ="yourValue", method = RequestMethod.POST)
protected ModelAndView showForm(@ModelAttribute("viewModel") TransferInvoice transferInvoice, final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response, Model model)throws Exception {
   //use every thing for transferInvoice
}
```

use `method = RequestMethod.POST`

Answer (score 0):

try replacing `path="TrinvoiceList[` with `path="transferinvoiceType[` and you should be good i believe. The problem here is you can access teh arraylist element which you are iterating using a value set for var attribute in c:foreach, and when you look at your code you see that you are trying to directly access the Attribute of object.

Comment: Please add more information (why is it right and other wrong etc.). Answers lower quality are quickly deleted. from the community !

Comment: Still getting the same 500 error. I have followed this solution here http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-mvc-multi-row-submit-java-list/